# How to have discord.py bot look for a message from a specific user recently?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a bot in writing in python and I want to incorporate a number game into the bot. The game code is below. (nl is a variable to say `os.linesep`)

```
    secret_number = random.randint(0, 100)
    guess_count = 0
    guess_limit = 5
    print(f'Welcome to the number guessing game! The range is 0 - 100 and you have 5 attempts to guess the correct number.')
    while guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = int(input('Guess: '))
        guess_count += 1
        if guess > secret_number:
            print('Too High.', nl, f"You have {guess_limit - guess_count} attempts remaining.")
        elif guess < secret_number:
            print('Too Low.', nl, f"You have {guess_limit - guess_count} attempts remaining.")
        elif guess == secret_number:
            print("That's correct, you won.")
            break

    else:
        print("Sorry, you failed.")
        print(f'The correct number was {secret_number}.')
```

So I want to be able to use that in the discord messaging system. My issue is that I need the bot to scan the most recent messages for a number from that specific user that initiated the game. How could I do so?
To simplify my question how can I say this:

```
if message from same message.author = int():
    guess = that^
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution here would be to [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) another message from that user. You can do this with:

```
msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=message.author == PREVIOUS_SAVED_MSG_AUTHOR_AS_VARIABLE, timeout=TIMEOUT) 
# You don't really need a timeout but you can add one if you want 
# (then you'd need a except asyncio.TimeoutError)
if msg.content == int():
    guess = msg
else:
    ...
```